# Reading the captured packet header features in snort

Tags: packet, snort

I need to deal with header features like duration and service (as HTTP),
How can I read these features by snort ?

The features I want are in the Image bellow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you connecting snort to the database, it will solve all problems.

[image]

Comment: I need command in snort to get the header information without connect snort to database.

Comment: I have never seen in the snort manual what you want features. If snort and database use together, log analysis more easier.

Comment: I added an Image contain the features that I want to read by snort, Please take a look

Comment: Snort is not A.I. You must make rules to detect traffic what you want. For example, `alert tcp any 143 <> any any (msg:"IMAP";)` http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node27.html